# jquery css backgroundposition animation with delay

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay, background-position

this works:

```
$("#header li a").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).fadeOut().delay(2000).fadeIn();
        },
        function(){
        }
    );
```

this not:

```
$("#header li a").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).css("background-position","center 0").delay(500).css("background-position","center -76px").delay(500).css("background-position","center -152px");
        },
        function(){
        }
    );
```

why?
just shows the last css value (center -152px).

Answer (score 1):

[`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) works on queues (most often animations), not on arbitrary functions. You should use `setTimeout()` instead.